# MariaDB - Column created with 'AS' has a default value of 1024

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this query

```
SELECT Stations.Instance
    ,stations.ID
    ,stations.Name
    ,Stations.Lat
    ,Stations.Lon
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Line SEPARATOR ';')
        FROM transportData.timeTables
        WHERE timeTables.Station = stations.ID
        GROUP BY timeTables.Station
        ) AS 'Lines'
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Weekdays SEPARATOR ';')
        FROM transportData.timeTables
        WHERE timeTables.Station = stations.ID
        GROUP BY timeTables.Station
        ) AS 'Weekdays'
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Weekends SEPARATOR ';')
        FROM transportData.timeTables
        WHERE timeTables.Station = stations.ID
        GROUP BY timeTables.Station
        ) AS 'Weekends'
FROM `Stations`
INNER JOIN transportData.stations ON stations.Lat = Stations.Lat
    AND stations.Lon = Stations.Lon
WHERE Instance = '$instance'
```

that is supposed to return in the Weekdays column a list of `Weekdays` that have the same `Station` column as the `ID` column of `transportData.stations`. Same goes for Weekends.

My issue here is the fact that these columns are usually large, about 2000 characters, and with this query, I could concatenate up to about 10 of these, so that's a lot of characters.

The query above works, but returns the Weekdays and Weekends with a maximum length of 1024, which is not at all enough.

How can I tell MariaDB that I want the result in more than 1024 characters?

Comment: Unrelated: Consider LEFT JOIN and conditional aggregation instead of those correlated sub-queries.

Comment: What datatype are your `transportData.timeTables.Weekdays` and `transportData.timeTables.Weekends` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend  the group_concat limit changing the  `my.ini`

```
group_concat_max_len = 10000
```

Comment: Right idea, but I don't think 10,000 is long enough to store 10 copies of a column with 2,000 characters.

Comment: This works great, I used the max length as the 32 bits maximum

Comment: My values  was  only a suggestion .. and the OP seems that have found the correct length..